# Adding external Google APIs to add-on initial auth scopes

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built a Google Sheets add-on that retrieves data from the Google Search Console API and writes it to the user's spreadsheets.

Since the Search Console API isn't available in the "Advanced Google services" section in Apps Script, I used the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) available on GitHub, with the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly" scope. It currently uses separate credentials in the Developer Console.

While the add-on works fairly well, when a user installs it for the first time, he/she has to authorize it using Google's OAuth process for certain scopes that are automatically detected in the script (managing spreadsheets, send emails, do external requests, and so on). After the authorization is completed, the add-on displays the usual add-on sidebar where the user has to do an **additional OAuth process**, this time for approving access to the Search Console API (via the OAuth2 library mentioned earlier).

My goal would be to include the Search Console scope in the initial OAuth process, so that users wouldn't need to go through the process twice. Unfortunately, the "Scopes" section in the Apps Script Project Properties isn't editable, so I cannot add that manually, and as far as I know there's no way to make it so it gets automatically detected.

Is there any way to do that? Would it make any difference if I were to use the Apps Script credentials for the OAuth2 library that I'm using to access the Search Console API (instead of having a separate set)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible to customize the OAuth list of a project via editing its manifest file: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

Google mentions that not all Google OAuth scopes are included (I haven't managed to find an exact list), but I've tested adding the Google Search Console scope and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external), Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web. This guide shows how to work with different types of APIs in your scripts. You can use the [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) service to make API requests directly.

> **Make requests to services with OAuth**
>
> APIs that act on behalf of a user usually require authorization, often using the [OAuth protocol](http://oauth.net/). Apps Script doesn't provide built-in support for the protocol, but there are open source libraries you can use to perform the OAuth flow and send the credentials with your requests:
>
> - [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1): Compatible with OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a.
> - [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2): Compatible with OAuth2.

This [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#user-content-making-http-requests-directly) might also help:

> **Making HTTP Requests Directly**
>
> If Google Authentication is desired for external applications, or a Google API is not available yet in this library, HTTP requests can be made directly.
>
> The `authorize` method returns an authorized [Guzzle Client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/), so any request made using the client will contain the corresponding authorization.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. I already use the OAuth2 library for Apps Script to connect to the API, I just need a way to integrate the scope within the Apps Script project scopes, so that users only need to authenticate once (when the add-on is installed), not twice.